# Simple Hello World WPF Application does not Launch on a few computers

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I developed a WPF application. After publishing it, I deployed it to the 4 client computers. It was working fine. However, two clients complained that it is not working on their computers. Their computers (Windows 7 and Windows 10) have the latest .NET framework installed. It was installed properly but failed to launch while displaying no error. Please note that there is a proper exception handling in the code. I was using **Setup and Deployment Wizard** of visual studio to publish it. Now I resorted to ClickOnce Publishing option, but that too showing the same result.

Now, I developed a simple Hello World WPF application without any third party references and tried to install it on the troublesome computers. This simple application also did install properly but failed to launch. I developed one simple Hello World Windows Forms application and that installed and executed properly.

Am I missing something here? Please help!

Comment: Maybe Event Log has something on those machines.

Comment: You should check out the Windows Event Log on the machines where your app fails to start. Look for error entries there.

Comment: Have you tried running with a debugger?

Comment: This is the Event Log:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          25/09/2019 15:38:58
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ITC-PC
Description:
Application: WPF_Test.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException
   at MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadNativeWPFDLL(UInt16*, UInt16*)
   at MS.Internal....

Comment: c++ Redistributables?  Can't recall if these are needed for a shell WPF app

Comment: [This issue might be caused by system failures in the .NET Framework. We suggest that you uninstall all the .NET Frameworks on your computer and reinstall them. This should do the trick.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dynamic-link-library/91846f62-942a-464d-b9f3-f5ab72f1a4d7)

Comment: @RobGoodwin Installed Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable. But still no luck.

Comment: Just set the build mode to release and rebuild the project and take all the files from the bin/release folder. That way is fool proof pretty much.

Comment: @EddyHoward It did not work either

Comment: After changing the TargetPlatform to x64, it is showing this error:

the procedure entry point leavecriticalsection could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-core-synch-i1-2-0.dll